# Can't deploy BAR file to BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha Simulator

Tags: eclipse, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I'm trying to port my Android app to BB10 using the BB Android Runtime SDK.  I've packaged the app OK and created a BAR file, but cannot get it installed on the BB 10 Dev Alpha simulator.  I've tried both running the app from Eclipse using Run As->BlackBerry Android Launch, and using the BlackBerry Tablet OS Graphical Aid 'Install' option, and in both cases I get this output :

```
Info: Sending request: Install
Info: Action: Install
Info: File size: 1709216
Info: Installing ...
Info: Processing 1709216 bytes
```

In Eclipse I also get the error 'Failed to deploy project ...'.  In the BB graphical aid I just get the above output in the 'Operation Output' window.  From seeing other posts it seems I should be seeing further log entries such as 'Info: Progress 0%...', 'Info: Progress 50%...' etc. which I don't see.  Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Is your problem resloved?

Comment: Hi, no I still have the same problem, even after installing the recent BB Android Tools update v.1.5.2.  I now test my app on a MacBook - the BAR file deploys every time to the OSX version of the Dev Alpha Simulator.  I'd still like to get it working on Windows though.

Comment: I also facing same problem, I also work on Windows OS but not able to deploy BB10 simulators.

Comment: what is failure 13 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have installed the brand new BB 10 Dev Simulator version 10.1 - the one that allows selecting to boot into Z10 or Q10 device, and I can now deploy my app every time on Windows.  Can only assume the problem was caused by bugs in the previous simulator version.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is double check if the application has already existed. If yes, you have to remove/uninstall it first from the simulator (by long-click on the application's icon and click the recycle icon at the top-right).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  Unfortunately this is not the case as I've yet to ever successfully install the app on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by completely uninstalling VMPlayer and the BB10 simulator, cleaning my registry and then reinstalling.  Still no idea why it wasn't working.

Comment: Spoke too soon, I was able to install 1 app after the re-install but since then I'm getting the same problem again.  No errors are reported, it just never completes the installation of the BAR file.